# Unable to display current location in Logs using LocationListener android studio 2.3

Tags: android, google-maps, android-logcat, locationlistener, currentlocation

I am trying To get the current location of the user and display it in Logs

Here is my Main Activity Java Code

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            Log.i("Location",location.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };

    //If the device is running version older than Marshmallow

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<23)
    {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
    }

    else
    {
        //Checking if it has permission access
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            //ask for permission

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);


        }
        else
        {
            //we have permission

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
    }
}
```

}

But I don't see The sales tag in my Logs, Here are the corresponding Logs:

[Here are My Logs](https://gist.github.com/khkr/ebc47c12233391a40dde482e4519a703)

I am new to Maps in Android , so I am not particularly sure where my code goes awry.

Comment: The way you are using the location services is obsolete. Please, check : https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html where you could find the recommended way. The actual way is through the Google Api Client which you ask for location updates (or the last known location if available). Hope it helps.

Comment: It actually looks like your code should work as-is.  What is the location mode set to on the device?

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to **Move** `LocationListener` outside of `onCreate()`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<23)
    {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
    }

    else
    {
        //Checking if it has permission access
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            //ask for permission

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);


        }
        else
        {
            //we have permission

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
        }
    }
}


  locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            Log.i("Location",location.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };

    .....
}
```

Then, **Modify** `onRequestPermissionResult()` as below:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please provide permission.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I move the `LocationListener` to

Comment: Just inside ur `MainActivity` class outside `onCreate`

Comment: But I did declare the `LocatinonListener` outside of onCreate

Comment: Yeah, you also have to move initialization and methods  of `LocationListener` outside `onCreate`. Check my updated answer please.